# How to install nodejs 4.4.3 LTS version on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, nodejs

I have tried to build it form the source using the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.3/node-v4.4.3.tar.gz
tar -xvzf node-v4.4.3.tar.gz
cd node-v4.4.3
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

Getting the error with `./configure` as mentioned below:

```
creating  ./icu_config.gypi
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                       'default_configuration': 'Release',
                       'defines': [],
                       'include_dirs': [],
                       'libraries': []},
  'variables': { 'asan': 0,
                 'gas_version': '2.22', 
....
....
       'v8_random_seed': 0,
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'true',
                 'want_separate_host_toolset': 0}}
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
gyp: /usr/local/src/node-v4.4.3/deps/cares/cares.gyp not found (cwd: /usr/local/src/node-v4.4.3) while loading dependencies of /usr/local/src/node-v4.4.3/node.gyp while trying to load /usr/local/src/node-v4.4.3/node.gyp
Error running GYP
```

As I have seen a issue on git [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6438), I have updated gcc to 4.8 & tired with 4.9 as well.. Error remains the same :|

Anyone has faced the same issue & know any solutions. Could anyone help with this?